# Regular Expression to match the value of a CSS calc inside a CSS transform

Tags: javascript, string, css-transforms, css-calc

I'm trying to extract the values of CSS transform strings using this regular expression `(\w+)\(([^)]*)\)` like `translateX(10px)` or `translateY(calc(-50% - 100px))`.

It works great on simple transform values like:
`translateX(10px)`
will returns
`translateX` and `10px`

But if I try to parse a CSS calc value:
`translateY(calc(-50% - 100px))`
it returns
`translateY` and `calc(-50% - 100px`

Notice the missing `)` at the end of `calc(-50% - 100px` ?

For now I managed to fix this problem by using this regular expression `/(\w+)(\([^)]*\)+)/g`, that  returns the values with the parenthesis and then slice the results to remove them :

`translateY(calc(-50% - 100px))`
returns:
`translateY` and `(calc(-50% - 100px))`;
then
`(calc(-50% - 100px)).slice(1, -1)`
returns:
`calc(-50% - 100px)`;

But this introduce an extra step and I was wondering if it was possible to do all that in one single Regular Expression.

Comment: Some regex flavours support recursion (of the whole pattern or part of it) which could gracefully solve your problem, but javascript doesn't. If your regexes are running under I don't think you can do better than your current solution

Comment: Regex isn't well suite for this issue. You're better off writing a simple parser which reads chars one by one and stores how many `(` have been opened and captures until the `)` equal the same amount.